# Which Earth species are extinct in the Star Trek universe?

Tags: star-trek, the-voyage-home

In *Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home*, we learn that humpback whales are extinct by the time of the Federation. My question is simple: are there any other species native to Earth that are extinct by that time?

Comment: Do dinosaurs count?

Comment: As evidenced by Valorum's question, I feel like this question needs to be focused quite a bit before it's a good question.  At the moment, it feels pretty broad...

Comment: I think we can assume asker is looking for species currently extant yet not yet extinct.

Comment: I think we can assume that Valorum's comment was tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: I've had another look around and I can't find anything additional to add to my existing answer. Is there anything you feel I should address?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [TNG: New Ground](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/210.txt), several prominent Earth species went extinct in the 21st and 22nd Century

- **Draco Lizards**

  > **KYLE:** *The eating habits of Gilvos are very similar to those of **Earth's Draco lizards, which died out over three hundred years ago...***

  [image]
- **White Rhinos**

  > **KYLE:** *... as the value of their horns increased, the number of white Rhinos in the wild kept falling until they finally became
  >   extinct about two centuries ago.*

  [image]
- By the 23rd Century ([TOS: Man Trap](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/6.htm)), the **Buffalo** was only a memory

  > **SPOCK:** *The Earth buffalo. What about it?*
  >
  > **CRATER:** *Once there were millions of them prairies black with them. One herd covered three whole states, and when they moved they
  >   were like thunder.*
  >
  > **SPOCK:** *And now they're gone. Is that what you mean?*

  [image]

Comment: Even a visionary like Roddenberry couldn't have foreseen the bison burger, which is what really saved the buffalo...